# Datatypes mismatch when calculating entropy with softmax

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

I am using below code to calculate entropy for the predicted labels and actual labels. Data is obtained from CIFAR-10 dataset.

I used astype(np.float32) to ocnvert the source data into ndarrays and thereafter used dtype as float32 in tf.constant(). The error message

> TypeError: DataType float32 for attr 'Tlabels' not in list of allowed
>   values: int32, int64

lists that only int32, int64 are allowed datatypes. Without explicitly specifying datatypes in above 2 steps, I face a roadblock at matmul() operation as weights term being used in the calculation is of float datatype.

```
f = open('cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_1', 'rb')
datadict = cPickle.load(f,encoding='bytes')
#f.close()
X = np.asarray(datadict[b"data"]).astype(np.float32)  #b prefix is for bytes string literal.
Y = np.asarray(datadict[b'labels']).astype(np.float32)
f = open('cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_1', 'rb')
datadict = cPickle.load(f,encoding='bytes')
#f.close()
X = np.asarray(datadict[b"data"]).astype(np.float32)  #b prefix is for bytes string literal.
Y = np.asarray(datadict[b'labels']).astype(np.float32)
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    tf_train_data = tf.constant(X, dtype = tf.float32)
    tf_train_labels = tf.constant(Y, dtype = tf.float32)
    tf_test_data = tf.constant(X_test, dtype = tf.float32)
    tf_test_labels = tf.constant(Y_test, dtype = tf.float32)
    print (tf_train_labels.get_shape())
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3072, 10]))
    print (tf.rank(weights))
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
    logits = tf.matmul(tf_train_data, weights) + biases
    print (tf.rank(logits), tf.rank(tf_train_labels), tf.rank(tf_test_labels))
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf_train_labels))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf_test_data, weights) + biases)
```

This is the error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-8e1ffbeb5013> in <module>()
     11     logits = tf.matmul(tf_train_data, weights) + biases
     12     print (tf.rank(logits), tf.rank(tf_train_labels), tf.rank(tf_test_labels))
---> 13     loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf_train_labels))
     14     optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
     15     train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

/Users/ayada/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels, name)
    562     if logits.get_shape().ndims == 2:
    563       cost, _ = gen_nn_ops._sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
--> 564           precise_logits, labels, name=name)
    565       if logits.dtype == dtypes.float16:
    566         return math_ops.cast(cost, dtypes.float16)

/Users/ayada/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py in _sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(features, labels, name)
   1538   """
   1539   result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits",
-> 1540                                 features=features, labels=labels, name=name)
   1541   return _SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogitsOutput._make(result)
   1542 

/Users/ayada/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    527             for base_type in base_types:
    528               _SatisfiesTypeConstraint(base_type,
--> 529                                        _Attr(op_def, input_arg.type_attr))
    530             attrs[input_arg.type_attr] = attr_value
    531             inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr] = input_name

/Users/ayada/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint(dtype, attr_def)
     58           "DataType %s for attr '%s' not in list of allowed values: %s" %
     59           (dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).name, attr_def.name,
---> 60            ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
     61 
     62 

TypeError: DataType float32 for attr 'Tlabels' not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
```

How can I fix it

Comment: try using astype('float') only. this might help.

Comment: Does tensorflow have a datatype float. From the documentation, I could only see it starts with float32. I tried it fron ndarrays but that did not help, https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/resources/dims_types.html

Answer (score 0):

`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` accepts sparse labels of integer type. To use one-hot float labels, consider using `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead.

Comment: I am using sparse labels, labels from input data is a list with corresponding classes for each input record. Do I need to convert the label to one-hot float label instead..

Comment: Just use integer datatype for them. Labels for sparse cross-entropy should be of type tf.int32 of tf.int64.

Comment: I did that but it wouldn't work because the weights tensor is initialized with truncated_normal() which returns a 2D float tensor. one of the matmul operations use input data, X_train and weights. For the matmul operation, I need to have X as float. I changed the labels into into int32 but that did not help

Comment: I fixed it by converting sparse labels into one-hot encoded labels.